# How to submit webpage in library?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a URL that I'd like to submit.  This will cause a redirect on the target page.  I'd then like to get the new URL.

This will occur inside of a library.  So no winforms or WPF.  Is there some type of web browser object available at this level (similar to the winforms web browser object)?

I don't need to do any page scraping.  Just access to the new URL.  But some type of eventing will need to be available so I'll know when it is ok to grab the new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HttpWebRequest:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(<submit URL>);
httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
// address after all redirections:
Uri address = httpWebRequest.Address;
```